# EF Core 6 Many to many table after scaffold

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've made a dotnet ef scaffold from database and the classes generated were:

```
public partial class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}


public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int? IdStudent { get; set; }
    public int? IdCourse { get; set; }

    public virtual Student? IdStudentNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Course? IdCourseNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a List of **Student** where id of **Course** is X

I've tried _context.Student.Include("StudentCourse").Where(x=>x.Any(....) but Intellisense does not accept "Any" function.

How can i get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Any(...)** is a method provided by **Enumerable** **class** so you can not use it on a single Student (which is obviously **not an Enumerable object**).
- Your configuration of many-to-many relationship is maybe missing some lines, here is my suggestion:

```
public partial class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}


public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int? IdStudent { get; set; }
    public int? IdCourse { get; set; }

    public virtual Student? StudentNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Course? CourseNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

In Context file:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                        .HasOne(sc => sc.StudentNavigation)
                        .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
                        .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.IdStudent);

            modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                        .HasOne(sc => sc.CourseNavigation)
                        .WithMany(c => c.StudentCourses)
                        .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.IdCourse);
  }
```

Finally, your query could be:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = await _context.Students
                                              .Include(s => s.StudentCourses)
                                              .Where(s => s.StudentCourses.Any(sc => sc.IdCourse == X)))
```

Comment: thank you, i'll try that. But why did the scaffold made it wrong then ? Maybe the database FK not properly made ? I think the foreign keys are OK

Answer (score 1):

If the DB is configured appropriately, then the current version of EF (EF7) will give you access to your many-to-many model without needing to use the mapping table.

You just need to ensure that your `StudentCourse` mapping table in the DB has a primary key defined consisting of both of your columns e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentCourse] (
    [StudentId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [CourseId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentCourse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentId] ASC, [CourseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourse_Student] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([StudentId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentCourse_Course] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseId])
);
```

Once you scaffold that, you will then end up with something like this along with the relevant EF config in your context:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}

public partial class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}
```

So you can then do this to get students where course is X:

```
var studentsWithCourseCalledX = context.Students.Where(s => s.Courses.Any(c => c.Name == "X"));
```

I was having the same issue as you i.e. scaffold not generating the many-to-many entity classes as expected. Once I defind the primary key with the 2 columns, the ef scaffold command produced the correct entity classes.

I found the hint in this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22475#issuecomment-691271085

Just checked and it's also referenced in the scaffold documentation many-to-many example, which I'd actually missed too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Just vaguely related.

Comment: Unfair Gert. The OP is struggling with ef scaffolding and retrieving data. I've given a precise answer as to why they might be having a scaffold issue, as described in the official documentation. I've also updated to show how to then use the newly scaffolded classes to get the data they want.

Comment: With the added explanation it's more obvious that there's a connection to OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking your code as example but this is not a way you design entity in EF core.

Try following though.

```
var students 
 =_context.StudentCourse.Include("IdStudentNavigation").Where(x=>x.IdCourse == 1).Select(x => x.IdStudentNavigation).ToList();
```

Replace one with your course id.

Comment: what's wrong with the design ? It was automatically created by database-first with dotnet scaffold